# How can I get a Hangfire job's end time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

Given a Hangfire job's ID, how can I get the time at which the job finished running?

I've tried the below, but the `JobData` class doesn't have a property for job end time.

```
IStorageConnection connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection();
JobData jobData = connection.GetJobData(jobId);
```

Comment: this might help: https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/job-duration-execution-end-time/4452

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a similar requirement before. Here is a method I wrote to get the `SucceededAt` property using the name of the running method and the current `PerformContext`:

```cs
public static DateTime? GetCompareDate(PerformContext context, string methodName)
{
    return long.TryParse(context.BackgroundJob.Id, out var currentJobId)
        ? JobStorage.Current
            ?.GetMonitoringApi()
            ?.SucceededJobs(0, (int)currentJobId)
            ?.LastOrDefault(x => x.Value?.Job?.Method?.Name == methodName).Value?.SucceededAt
        : null;
}
```

You could just as easily get `DeletedJobs`, `EnqueuedJobs`, `FailedJobs`, etc.

You can call it from a job method like this:

```cs
public async Task SomeJob(PerformContext context, CancellationToken token)
{
    ⋮
    var compareDate = GetCompareDate(context, nameof(SomeJob));
    ⋮
}
```

You just have to add the `PerformContext` when adding the job by passing in `null`:

```cs
RecurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate(
        recurringJobId: "1",
        job: Job.FromExpression(() => SomeJob(null, CancellationToken.None)),
        cronExpression: Cron.Hourly(15),
        options: new RecurringJobOptions
        {
            TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local
        });
```

Note: It will only work if the succeeded job has not expired yet. Successful jobs expire after one day - if you need to keep them longer (to get the `SucceededAt` property), here is a reference for that: [How to configure the retention time of job?](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-configure-the-retention-time-of-job/34)

Comment: This looks promising. Is there no way to get it for *any* job—whether it succeeded or failed? I don't see an "all jobs" method in the monitoring API, which seems like a gap. I'm thinking about a pull request to add one if there isn't a better way.

Comment: I haven't found one, unfortunately. I initially tried the approach you used in your question (i.e. `using (var connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection())`), but the methods exposed on the `connection` are very limited and I couldn't get what I needed from it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Stopwatch class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) when you first call the task and stop it when the task is completed.

Then you could use a log nugget to generate a txt log file containing the start time and end time of your job. Or directly save this values to your database so that you can review them later.

Comment: The only problems I see are (1) data redundancy and (2) failed jobs. For #1, I feel like Hangfire should ideally be the SSOT and we could get job metadata from it instead of creating a second data store. For #2, I guess all jobs could inherit an abstract class with a `RunJobAsync` method that calls an internal abstract `RunJobInternalAsync` method. `RunJobAsync` wraps the call to `RunJobInternalAsync` in a `try`-`catch` block and `finally` logs the end time. I'd rather not force inheritance, though. Or we could write a filter. But Hangfire's DI for filters is pretty bad right now.